# How to avoid looping over list after reading from JSON with R

Tags: json, r

I have a vector of JSON data in R, and with lapply I extract the information:

```
 list <- lapply(temp, fromJSON)
```

The structure of the first element of this list looks like this:

```
str(list[[1]])

List of 4
 $ boundedBy :List of 2
  ..$ type       : chr "Polygon"
  ..$ coordinates:List of 1
  .. ..$ :List of 5
  .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 89328 208707
  .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 89333 208707
  .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 89333 208713
  .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 89328 208713
  .. .. ..$ : num [1:2] 89328 208707
 $ hnrlbl    : NULL
 $ opndatum  : chr "2011-05-30"
 $ oidn      : chr "2954841"
```

This works for the first element: `list[[1]]$hnrlbl` , but how do I do this at once for the whole list? Something like `list[[.]]$hnrlbl`

Comment: You want to extract hnrlbl from each list item?

Comment: Can you provide `dput(list)`? Also, do you consider `lapply` as "looping"?

Comment: @mcuelenaere yes that is exactly what I want to do

Comment: @DavidArenburg No I don't consider lapply as looping, that would be fine. What do you think of the answer I gave? If you see something cleaner and faster, I am happy to send you the list.

Comment: It looks the usual way to solves these kind of problems

Answer (score 4):

In this case you could just use `list.map` from the `rlist` package:

```
mylist <- lapply(temp, fromJSON)
library(rlist)
list.map(mylist, hnrlbl)
```

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlist/vignettes/Mapping.html

Comment: Definitely an easy way of doing it. As `list.map` is based on mapply, this is still an intrinsic loop function and not necessarily faster than `sapply()` though.

Answer (score 3):

I have a helper function that's useful for these scenarios:

```
pluck <- function(x, name, type) {
  if (missing(type)) {
    lapply(x, .subset2, name)
  } else {
    vapply(x, .subset2, name, FUN.VALUE = type)
  }
}
```

(This was inspired by [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) & Winston
Chang. `.subset2()` is an internal version of `[[` - it's faster, but
doesn't do S3 dispatch which means that `x` needs to be a plain list).

With this function, solving your problem is easy:

```
x <- list(
  a = list(x = rnorm(10), y = letters[1:10], z = "OK"),
  b = list(x = rnorm(10), y = letters[11:20], z = "notOK")
)

# List of results
str(pluck(x, "z"))
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: chr "OK"
#>  $ b: chr "notOK"

# Vector of results
str(pluck(x, "z", character(1)))
#>  Named chr [1:2] "OK" "notOK"
#>  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "a" "b"
```

(You can also select by position: `pluck(x, 2, character(10))`)

### Benchmarking

This method is also quite fast:

```
x_big <- rep(x, 1000)

myselect <- function(x,name){
  tmp <- unlist(x, recursive = FALSE)
  id <- grep(paste0("\\.",name,"$"), names(tmp))
  tmp[id]
}

library(microbenchmark)
options(digits = 2)
microbenchmark(
  sapply(x_big, function(i)i$z),
  myselect(x_big,"z"),
  pluck(x_big, "z", character(1))
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                             expr  min   lq median   uq  max neval
#>   sapply(x_big, function(i) i$z) 2771 2886   2972 3124 5903   100
#>             myselect(x_big, "z") 2250 2330   2366 2401 3551   100
#>  pluck(x_big, "z", character(1))  717  786    825  889 1731   100
```

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours looking for the cleanest method, we did:

```
 kadaster_building_temp$hnrlbl <- sapply(list,function(x){x$hnrlbl} )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** : by using regular expressions, this solution might fail under some conditions (depending on the names you use in your lists). If speed is not an option, either `list.map` or the solution using `sapply` are more robust

---

You can gain quite some speed by using `unlist()` here and look for the names. Take the following function `myselect`:

```
myselect <- function(x,name){
  tmp <- unlist(x,recursive=FALSE)
  id <- grep(paste0("(^|\\.)",name,"$"),names(tmp))
  tmp[id]
}
```

This one does about the same but in a vectorized way. By using the argument `recursive=FALSE`, you flatten the nested list to a flat list (all elements are part of the same list). Then you use the naming convention used by this function to look for all the elements that contain the exact name you want to select. Hence the call to `paste0` to construct a regular expression that avoids partial name matches. Simple selection returns you again a list with the wanted elements. If you want this to be a vector or so, you can simply use `unlist()` on the result.

Note that I presume you have a list of lists, so you only want to flatten one level. For more complicated nesting, this obviously won't work in the current form.

---

**Example and Benchmarking**

The speed gain is dependent on the structure of the list obviously, but can go up to a 50fold or more speed gain.

Take following (very basic) example:

```
aList <- list(
  a=list(x=rnorm(10),y=letters[1:10],z="OK"),
  b=list(x=rnorm(10),y=letters[11:20],z="notOK")
  )
```

Benchmarking this gives:

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(
  sapply(aList,function(i)i$z),
  myselect(aList,"z"),
  columns=c("test","elapsed","relative"),
  replications=10000
  )

                            test elapsed relative
2           myselect(aList, "z")    0.24    1.000
1 sapply(aList, function(i) i$z)    0.39    1.625
```

With larger objects, the improvement can be substantial. Using this on a list I happened to have in my workspace (dput is not an option here...):

```
> benchmark(
+   sapply(StatN0_1,function(i)i$SP),
+   myselect(StatN0_1,"SP"),
+   columns=c("test","elapsed","relative"),
+   replications=100
+ )
                                test elapsed relative
2           myselect(StatN0_1, "SP")    0.02      1.0
1 sapply(StatN0_1, function(i) i$SP)    1.13     56.5
```

Comment: This method assumes the top level list is named, and using regular expressions is going to be pretty brittle.

Comment: @hadley Adapted to allow for a non-named top level list. I agree on using regexes being brittle, which is why I stressed that this is for speed gain in this particular case. I added a sentence to reflect that.

Comment: To paraphrase: "He who gives up safety for speed deserves neither."